# I'm trying to solve the ff differential calculus question? It's pretty basic but I'm at a loss as to the concept

Tags: calculus

Please, how do I go about this problem: d^2/dxdy (2x + 3y). How do I go about finding the derivative? Do I take the derivative of the function w.r.t to x then find the derivative of the answer w.r.t y?

In another example (which is my real problem) the function includes a z component, as in say, 2x + 3y + 2z. But it's the same d^2/dxdy that's operating on it. is the z component treated as  a constant so that by the first act of differentiation of x, for instance, it leaves the function. or is maintained?

Comment: The notation $\dfrac{\mathrm d^2f}{\mathrm dx\mathrm dy}$ is short for $\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\dfrac{\mathrm df}{\mathrm dy}\right)$, so you should first take the derivative with respect to $y$ and then take the derivative of what you got with respect to $x$. In this case, however, because $(x,y)\mapsto 2x+3y$ is class $C^1$, the order doesn't matter.

Comment: Exactly. You take the derivative of the function with respect to $x$, then find the derivative of the answer with respect to $y$. You can do $y$ then $x$ too, and you'll get the same answer, which is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't comment, I'm creating an answer. The answer to your question is yes. Maybe look up [partial derivatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative).